# Parsing data in awk

Tags: python, bash, parsing, awk, sed

I have a genetics data like this:

```
MUT1    G_->_A_(het)    44%_(96)___[45%_(49)_/_43%_(47)]    rs1799967_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP,MutDB) c.4956G>A   1
MUT1    A_->_G_(homo)   99%_(297)___[99%_(151)_/_99%_(146)] rs206075_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP)    c.4563A>G   1
MUT1    G_->_C_(homo)   100%_(259)___[100%_(132)_/_100%_(127)]  COSM4147689_(COSMIC),_COSM4147690_(COSMIC),_rs206076_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVar;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP)   c.6513G>C   2
MUT1    A_->_C_(het)    41%_(103)___[42%_(53)_/_40%_(50)]   COSM3753646_(COSMIC),_COSM147663_(COSMIC),_rs144848_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP,MutDB)   c.1114A>C   5
```

What I need to parse this data and extract only some kind of fields.

Require output is:

```
MUT1    het 44% rs1799967 c.4956G>A 1
MUT1    homo 99% rs206075c.4563A>G  1
MUT1    homo 100% rs206076 c.6513G>C    2
MUT1    het 41% rs144848 c.1114A>C  5
```

So output shoould be - **all first** column, from second column only **het or hom**, third column is only **%**, fifth column should be extracted only **rs_number** - this have always different position and last column.

note: I know, that info about homo/het is always in last filed of second column. And % is always on first field in third column.

My solution is:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$5,$6,$9,$10,$11}' zkouska.csv | awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR>1{split($2,arr2,"_"); split($3,arr3,"_"); print $1,arr2[4],arr3[1],$4,$5,$6}'
```

But output is :

```
BRCA1   (het)   44% rs1799967_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP,MutDB) c.4956G>A   1
BRCA1   (homo)  99% rs206075_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP)    c.4563A>G   1
BRCA1   (homo)  100%    COSM4147689_(COSMIC),_COSM4147690_(COSMIC),_rs206076_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVar;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP)   c.6513G>C   2
BRCA1   (het)   41% COSM3753646_(COSMIC),_COSM147663_(COSMIC),_rs144848_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP,MutDB)   c.1114A>C   5
BRCA1   (homo)  100%    COSM148277_(COSMIC),_COSM3755561_(COSMIC),_rs16942_(Gene_file;_1000Genomes;_ClinVarVCF;_dbSNP)  c.3548A>G   5
```

Still have problem to extract **rs** from fifth column. Erase quotes in second field. Inpout and output should be TAB separate. **Solution could no be only in awk.**

Comment: is `perl` okay? you could use `perl -ne 'print join "\t", /^(\S+)/,/^[^(]+\(\K([^)]+)/,/^[^)]+\)\s+\K(\d+%)/,/(rs\d+)/,/\S+\s+\S+\s*$/g' file` which looks complicated but just a bunch of extracted text strung together...

Comment: Is the file size expected to be large? near 1000 of lines, for string manipulation as in here, `bash` could have handy tricks, but doesn't scale for bigger files

Comment: I dont think there would be a more than 1000 lines. And this is not problem when parsing takes a while.

Comment: @Sundeep thank you for perl solution. I have an error Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after ,/(rs\d+)/<-- HERE near column 78 at -e line 1.

Comment: You can use the `match()` function to find the strings matching the pattern `rs[0-9]+`.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Problem is, that number after rs is not always the same length :(

Comment: @Geroge for some reason some weird invisible characters got added, no idea why... I'll put it as an answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of `gsub` and `match` might be the way to go, here is a portable example:

*parse.awk*

```awk
{
  gsub(/^[^(]+\(|\)/, "", $2)
  gsub(/_.*/, "", $3)
  match($4, /rs[0-9]+/)
  print $1, $2, $3, substr($4, RSTART, RLENGTH), $5, $6
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk OFS='\t' < infile
```

Output:

```
MUT1    het     44%     rs1799967   c.4956G>A   1
MUT1    homo    99%     rs206075    c.4563A>G   1
MUT1    homo    100%    rs206076    c.6513G>C   2
MUT1    het     41%     rs144848    c.1114A>C   5
```

Comment: Awesome solution and very easy - nice use gsub and match. Thank you so much!

Comment: I checked solution and in output is missing % info.

Comment: @Thor thank you. I am accepting your answer - because I am prefer awk solution. But perl and bash solution gives me some new knowledge and I am appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\t", /^(\S+)/,/^[^(]+\(\K([^)]+)/,/^[^)]+\)\s+\K(\d+%)/,/(rs\d+)/,/(\S+\s+\S+)\s*$/' file
MUT1    het 44% rs1799967   c.4956G>A   1
MUT1    homo    99% rs206075    c.4563A>G   1
MUT1    homo    100%    rs206076    c.6513G>C   2
MUT1    het 41% rs144848    c.1114A>C   5
```

- `/^(\S+)/` extract non-whitespace characters from start of line
- `/^[^(]+\(\K([^)]+)/` extract characters between first `()`
- `/^[^)]+\)\s+\K(\d+%)/` extract first match of digits followed by % after first `)` in the line
- `/(rs\d+)/` extract `rs` followed by digits
- `/(\S+\s+\S+)\s*$/` extract last two columns

Another way is to process each field separately, similar to `bash` and `awk` solutions

```
$ perl -lane '
$F[1] =~ s/.*\(|\)//g;
$F[2] =~ s/_.*//;
($F[3]) = $F[3] =~ m/(rs\d+)/;
print join "\t", @F;
' file
MUT1    het 44% rs1799967   c.4956G>A   1
MUT1    homo    99% rs206075    c.4563A>G   1
MUT1    homo    100%    rs206076    c.6513G>C   2
MUT1    het 41% rs144848    c.1114A>C   5
```

Answer (score 3):

Am posting a pure `bash` logic for your requirement.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
do
    subcol2="${col2#*(}";subcol2=${subcol2%)*}                             # Extracting string within the braces '()' using parameter-expansion              
    [[ $col4 =~ .*rs([[:digit:]]+).* ]] && subcol4="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"    # RegEx in bash to extract number following the 'rs' string
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" "$col1" "$subcol2" "${col3%%_*}" "rs$subcol4" "$col5" "$col6"
done <file
```

On running the script, produces the result as

```
$ bash script.sh
MUT1 het 44% rs1799967 c.4956G>A 1
MUT1 homo 99% rs206075 c.4563A>G 1
MUT1 homo 100% rs206076 c.6513G>C 2
MUT1 het 41% rs144848 c.1114A>C 5
```

**NOTE**: The solution may perform slower on bigger files. I have tested this only on your sample file.

Comment: bash still surprise me. Very nice and working solution- thank you!